# Close Activity on closing PlacePicker

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

As I understand, PlacePicker is a widget that comes on top of an Activity or Fragment. 
I want to handle the back button to close the activity as well as the PlacePicker when I click on it.

[PlacePicker with Default Android Navigation at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgFZB.png)

Right now, when I press the back button the PlacePicker closes first and the activity closes only after I press the back button again.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

The above code is only executed after the PlacePicker is closed on click of the back button the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I could not find a direct solution, I was able to solve this with initiating the PlacePicker at the calling activity only.

To show the details returned by the PlacePicker, I used another activity with the help of an Intent.